# Ender 3 printer won't auto home

Tags: firmware, creality, ender3

After building my Ender 3 printer, installing the CR touch auto bed leveling kit, and the Ender-3 Marlin2.0.6 CR-Touch or BLTouch firmware for it. I turned it on and tried to auto home but it just made a little noise and then displayed "Homing failed printer halted please restart". So I tested the end stops with a multimeter and they all seemed fine. I did some research and found the CR touch firmware could be the problem and installed some newer firmware (Ender-3Marlin2.0.6HW4.2.2GD) and nothing has changed. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

The reason I was having this problem was because of a file I had extracted that was on the sd card.
I noticed an orange dot at the end of the extracted file, so I thought it was probably flashing and interfering with the firmware. After I deleted the extracted file and flashed the firmware it ran perfectly.

Comment: Where was the "orange dot", and how did you see it? Was it in the filename, or inside the file when viewed with.text editor, or did you see it in some other manner?

Comment: Also, please don't forget to mark your answer as the "accepted answer" (you may have to wait up to 48 hours). Thanks.

Comment: This answer doesn't make much sense to me. You got it homing, but not working with the CR Touch? Shouldn't that be the crux of the question, i.e. getting it to home with the leveling sensor?